# print Two-Dimensional Array like table in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, multidimensional-array

I'm having a problem with two dimensional array. I want the array to be like a table and not say Array (), Array().

Something like this :

```
 ........
 ........
 ........
 ........     
 ........
 ........
 ........
 ........
 ........

 scala> val table = Array.fill(9,8)('.')
 table: Array[Array[Char]] = Array(Array(., ., ., ., ., ., ., .), Array(., ., ., ., ., ., ., .),     
 Array(., ., ., ., ., ., ., .), Array(., ., ., ., ., ., ., .), Array(., ., ., ., ., ., ., .),   
 Array(., ., ., ., ., ., ., .), Array(., ., ., ., ., ., ., .), Array(., ., ., ., ., ., ., .),   
 Array(., ., ., ., ., ., ., .))
```

Comment: what do you mean "like a table"? 
"a table" is Array[Array[Something]] anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `print`, `println`, and `foreach` for the desired effect:

```
table foreach { row => row foreach print; println }
```

You can also use the `mkString` method on collections, which joins the elements of the list (either with no delimeter, or with an overload that provides a string delimeter):

```
print(table.map(_.mkString).mkString("\n"))
```

Comment: or table.foreach( x => println(x.mkString) )

Comment: thanks! do you by ant chance know how i would be able to target a specific row in the array, just to change the values in that row? @kaktusito

Comment: Please open a new question for unrelated questions.  Please Google a little bit first and let us know what you tried and what your challenge is.  I encourage you to do the Stackoverflow tour (help -> tour in the upper right corner)!

Comment: For those having trouble understanding the point-free syntax, it's `table.foreach { row => row.foreach(print); println() }`. `print` prints the row and `println` prints a newline. Also, don't hard code newline character `\n`, instead use  platform-dependent `System.lineSeparator()`. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val arr: Array[Array[Int]] = Array.ofDim(2,2)
val arr: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0), Array(0, 0))

scala> arr.map(_.mkString(" ")).foreach(println)
0 0
0 0
```